# React-native: Layout a view next to a centered one

Tags: react-native, layout, flexbox

I want to achieve the following:

[image]

I want to display a label next to a centered value.
As far as I can see that's not possible with flexbox, right?
How could I achieve that?

Additionally I'd like to have the base-aligned, but currently this option is not working on Android. Therefore I'm using hardcoded paddings for the smaller text boxes. Any other Idea for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another suggestion, if you don't want to use empty `View`s, is to position `Value` to the center, and then have the `unit` positioned `absolute` (so it goes off the flex) and to the `bottom` so you ensure it's base-aligned to `Value`.

[image]

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.value}>
    Value
    <Text style={styles.unit}>unit</Text>
  </Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
  },
  value: {
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  unit: {
    fontSize: 12,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use 3 flex boxes placed horizontally to get a similar effect. Leave the left box blank.

[image]

(Ive added background colors for reference)

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
      }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1}} /> {/* blank view */}
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Value</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          alignItems: 'fllex-start',
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Unit</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
```